# Samba share unavailable on Windows 10 after copying file

Tags: permissions, samba

I have a Samba share running off Ubuntu 18.04, which has run for some time without issue. Now when I access that share on a Windows 10 machine it works just fine, until I delete or copy a file to the share. The deleting or copying of the file works, but then it becomes no longer available until I reboot the Windows 10 machine. Reading works without issue. I have this problem on multiple Windows 10 machines. Logs reveal this error:

```
[2019/05/30 06:30:15.187133,  0] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:3350(process_usershare_file)
  process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/storage failed. Permission denied
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For guests access.

- Give read/write permissions:

  ```
  sudo chmod -R +rwx /var/lib/samba/usershares/storage
  ```
- Change owner:

  ```
  sudo chown -R nobody:nogroup /var/lib/samba/usershares/storage
  ```

Make a backup of your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file then modify your configuration file putting there the lines if not present:

```
[global]
    guest account = nobody
    usershare allow guests = Yes

[storage]
  path = /var/lib/samba/usershares/storage
  comment = sambashare on Ubuntu
  directory mask = 0755
  create mode = 0777
  read only = no
  available = yes
  browseable = yes
  writable = yes
  guest ok = yes
  public = yes
  locking = no
  strict locking = no
```